# SQL does not fetch today's transaction when using trunc

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get all rowsprior to current time and date including today's transactions.

```
select * from mytable 
where joindate <= trunc(sysdate)
```

I did not get rows that belong to today.

AM I doing any thing wrong.

Comment: what the format of joindate? is it datetime? timestamp?

Comment: @ManinGreen. The format of joindate is Date

Comment: If you want today's data, then don't use trunc.

Comment: @EatÅPeach. Can you tell me what to use instead of trunc.

Comment: @Patan, joindate <= sysdate

Comment: @EatÅPeach: That won't include joindates from later today, though.

Comment: @Thilo - it doesn't need to, according to the question - "all rows prior to current time". I'd actually read it as a column that can't have future dates/times anyway, which would make the whole condition pointless, so it's still open to interpretation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run

```
select trunc(sysdate) from dual;
```

and you will see an output like `2014-05-24 00:00:00`. `trunc` sets the time to midnight.

You can try

```
where joindate < trunc(sysdate)+1
```

to look for all `joindate`s before `2014-05-25 00:00:00` which should meet your requirements.

Comment: select trunc(sysdate) from dual; gives 2014-05-27

Comment: depends on your configuration of your sql client; maybe it's configured not show the full datetime format. internally, it is `2014-05-27 00:00:00`.

Comment: where joindate < trunc(sysdate)+1 .Also did not work. Still i dinot get today's rows.

Comment: I rechecked my answer and it works here. You're sure, that you have some rows with today as joindate?

Comment: Yeah I have some data for todays transactions

Comment: It works here. Please create a sql fiddle to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Patan - is your data from today committed?

Comment: yes it is committed. Still unable to figure out the mistake :(

Comment: @Patan - what is shown here should work, so something is missing from the description you've given. Maybe your real query has other conditions that aren't being met, for example. Can you add some sample data to the question which demonstrates this issue, including the full date and time in `joindate`; or create a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) as suggested before. Otherwise we can't tell what you might be doing differently, or wrong.